RSA decryption does not work when saved as base64
I'm trying to encrypt data, save the encrypted data as a base64 string and then use the base64 string to decrypt it again. This works when I base64 encode and decode in the same function but this won't work if I take the base64 string from my sql database.
To simulate this I created this example:
//THIS DOES WORK
var normal_text = "hi";
var bytes = utf8.encode(normal_text);
var encoded = rsaEncrypt(publicRSA, bytes);
var base64_encoded = base64Encode(encoded);
debugPrint(base64_encoded); // used this in var base64
var encrypted_bytes = base64Decode(base64_encoded);
debugPrint(encrypted_bytes.toString());
var decoded = rsaDecrypt(privateRSA, encrypted_bytes);
debugPrint(utf8.decode(decoded).toString());


//THIS DOES NOT WORK
var base64 = "";
var encrypted_bytes2 = base64Decode(base64);
debugPrint(encrypted_bytes2.toString());
var decoded2 = rsaDecrypt(privateRSA, encrypted_bytes2);
debugPrint(utf8.decode(decoded2).toString());

Results:
flutter: T+xdCQMsicw4E/kaQ7jD2ZLLMrP7j2DMQCCxT6K0i6ULi/UIGjsx5PFSeu+e4zftF9u0w6aZowedTeU3+topgPyPVeor/fQWfqe+LEarfph56Ws1mOPQLjXcRlH3mZBfmjLC5OKOm/UmqJxCtQoVk+c3xeT4uOFauJb7i2jQaTB3VZqe800Uk0bBEufUTMNO7ywvDVjq5gPUvYHbQ9i27laig38yiR/p2TQIUw/Wc/AXdA+7mSJA+/F0IKTpHVegFKmAUi1+ERRlaZs5ny2hS1Mt9og4BjfAGkWXB2Hxz5KMySFGDkOtDdWCwxiFroapK/nQ72Gh50nfKYenecWBjw==
flutter: [79, 236, 93, 9, 3, 44, 137, 204, 56, 19, 249, 26, 67, 184, 195, 217, 146, 203, 50, 179, 251, 143, 96, 204, 64, 32, 177, 79, 162, 180, 139, 165, 11, 139, 245, 8, 26, 59, 49, 228, 241, 82, 122, 239, 158, 227, 55, 237, 23, 219, 180, 195, 166, 153, 163, 7, 157, 77, 229, 55, 250, 218, 41, 128, 252, 143, 85, 234, 43, 253, 244, 22, 126, 167, 190, 44, 70, 171, 126, 152, 121, 233, 107, 53, 152, 227, 208, 46, 53, 220, 70, 81, 247, 153, 144, 95, 154, 50, 194, 228, 226, 142, 155, 245, 38, 168, 156, 66, 181, 10, 21, 147, 231, 55, 197, 228, 248, 184, 225, 90, 184, 150, 251, 139, 104, 208, 105, 48, 119, 85, 154, 158, 243, 77, 20, 147, 70, 193, 18, 231, 212, 76, 195, 78, 239, 44, 47, 13, 88, 234, 230, 3, 212, 189, 129, 219, 67, 216, 182, 238, 86, 162, 131, 127, 50, 137, 31, 233, 217, 52, 8, 83, 15, 214, 115, 240, 23, 116, 15, 187, 153, 34, 64, 251, 241, 116, 32, 164, 233, 29, 87, 160, 20, 169, 128, 82, 45, 126, 17, 20, 101, 105, 155, 57, 159, 45, 161, 75, 83, 45, 246, 136, 56, 6, 55, 192, 26, 69, 151, 7, 97, 241, 207, 146, 140, 201, 33, 70, 14, 67, 173, 13, 213, 130, 195, 24, 133, 174, 134, 169, 43, 249, 208, 239, 97, 161, 231, 73, 223, 41, 135, 167, 121, 197, 129, 143]
flutter: hi
flutter: []
flutter: 

Then running it again and using the debugPrinted base64 string as input for the second part:
//THIS DOES WORK
var normal_text = "hi";
var bytes = utf8.encode(normal_text);
var encoded = rsaEncrypt(publicRSA, bytes);
var base64_encoded = base64Encode(encoded);
debugPrint(base64_encoded); // used this in var base64
var encrypted_bytes = base64Decode(base64_encoded);
debugPrint(encrypted_bytes.toString());
var decoded = rsaDecrypt(privateRSA, encrypted_bytes);
debugPrint(utf8.decode(decoded).toString());


//THIS DOES NOT WORK
var base64 = "T+xdCQMsicw4E/kaQ7jD2ZLLMrP7j2DMQCCxT6K0i6ULi/UIGjsx5PFSeu+e4zftF9u0w6aZowedTeU3+topgPyPVeor/fQWfqe+LEarfph56Ws1mOPQLjXcRlH3mZBfmjLC5OKOm/UmqJxCtQoVk+c3xeT4uOFauJb7i2jQaTB3VZqe800Uk0bBEufUTMNO7ywvDVjq5gPUvYHbQ9i27laig38yiR/p2TQIUw/Wc/AXdA+7mSJA+/F0IKTpHVegFKmAUi1+ERRlaZs5ny2hS1Mt9og4BjfAGkWXB2Hxz5KMySFGDkOtDdWCwxiFroapK/nQ72Gh50nfKYenecWBjw==";
var encrypted_bytes2 = base64Decode(base64);
debugPrint(encrypted_bytes2.toString());
var decoded2 = rsaDecrypt(privateRSA, encrypted_bytes2);
debugPrint(utf8.decode(decoded2).toString());

2nd results:
flutter: PRt/Zg7KxEGHslGT11Vytd1Y4V+dudvT6XPEYQDTb9tZKGRvk+i7pVut5Nz2+2E3RFNKn/NOgbwht9sPYiKOUVW7PmKmHAjskTHYwjxizDxgl6VTFuhwqJeSSEpoLuRUWJRI/zynp/Np4hi3CvEtPq0ZzIBj19sgOg4p0N99/NawJUTYlvTnKuHb8TpYUzyPqiGVdQAC4oQALa8NVhLtAmkGCHdDIcCsT4jcmARJmv5qugVTrFFwF0GQj0mZn/7oA9iO1Ev22Y0PlmYzvYiBOeO3+qMgtU3b/jfeTDnHDA4OgGMXIw8IiiDWV04w6+r5k6JBG5mwb6eZxK9vjEz4Dw==
flutter: [61, 27, 127, 102, 14, 202, 196, 65, 135, 178, 81, 147, 215, 85, 114, 181, 221, 88, 225, 95, 157, 185, 219, 211, 233, 115, 196, 97, 0, 211, 111, 219, 89, 40, 100, 111, 147, 232, 187, 165, 91, 173, 228, 220, 246, 251, 97, 55, 68, 83, 74, 159, 243, 78, 129, 188, 33, 183, 219, 15, 98, 34, 142, 81, 85, 187, 62, 98, 166, 28, 8, 236, 145, 49, 216, 194, 60, 98, 204, 60, 96, 151, 165, 83, 22, 232, 112, 168, 151, 146, 72, 74, 104, 46, 228, 84, 88, 148, 72, 255, 60, 167, 167, 243, 105, 226, 24, 183, 10, 241, 45, 62, 173, 25, 204, 128, 99, 215, 219, 32, 58, 14, 41, 208, 223, 125, 252, 214, 176, 37, 68, 216, 150, 244, 231, 42, 225, 219, 241, 58, 88, 83, 60, 143, 170, 33, 149, 117, 0, 2, 226, 132, 0, 45, 175, 13, 86, 18, 237, 2, 105, 6, 8, 119, 67, 33, 192, 172, 79, 136, 220, 152, 4, 73, 154, 254, 106, 186, 5, 83, 172, 81, 112, 23, 65, 144, 143, 73, 153, 159, 254, 232, 3, 216, 142, 212, 75, 246, 217, 141, 15, 150, 102, 51, 189, 136, 129, 57, 227, 183, 250, 163, 32, 181, 77, 219, 254, 55, 222, 76, 57, 199, 12, 14, 14, 128, 99, 23, 35, 15, 8, 138, 32, 214, 87, 78, 48, 235, 234, 249, 147, 162, 65, 27, 153, 176, 111, 167, 153, 196, 175, 111, 140, 76, 248, 15]
flutter: hi
flutter: [79, 236, 93, 9, 3, 44, 137, 204, 56, 19, 249, 26, 67, 184, 195, 217, 146, 203, 50, 179, 251, 143, 96, 204, 64, 32, 177, 79, 162, 180, 139, 165, 11, 139, 245, 8, 26, 59, 49, 228, 241, 82, 122, 239, 158, 227, 55, 237, 23, 219, 180, 195, 166, 153, 163, 7, 157, 77, 229, 55, 250, 218, 41, 128, 252, 143, 85, 234, 43, 253, 244, 22, 126, 167, 190, 44, 70, 171, 126, 152, 121, 233, 107, 53, 152, 227, 208, 46, 53, 220, 70, 81, 247, 153, 144, 95, 154, 50, 194, 228, 226, 142, 155, 245, 38, 168, 156, 66, 181, 10, 21, 147, 231, 55, 197, 228, 248, 184, 225, 90, 184, 150, 251, 139, 104, 208, 105, 48, 119, 85, 154, 158, 243, 77, 20, 147, 70, 193, 18, 231, 212, 76, 195, 78, 239, 44, 47, 13, 88, 234, 230, 3, 212, 189, 129, 219, 67, 216, 182, 238, 86, 162, 131, 127, 50, 137, 31, 233, 217, 52, 8, 83, 15, 214, 115, 240, 23, 116, 15, 187, 153, 34, 64, 251, 241, 116, 32, 164, 233, 29, 87, 160, 20, 169, 128, 82, 45, 126, 17, 20, 101, 105, 155, 57, 159, 45, 161, 75, 83, 45, 246, 136, 56, 6, 55, 192, 26, 69, 151, 7, 97, 241, 207, 146, 140, 201, 33, 70, 14, 67, 173, 13, 213, 130, 195, 24, 133, 174, 134, 169, 43, 249, 208, 239, 97, 161, 231, 73, 223, 41, 135, 167, 121, 197, 129, 143]
[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: Invalid argument(s): decoding error
#0      OAEPEncoding._decodeBlock (package:pointycastle/asymmetric/oaep.dart:457:7)
#1      OAEPEncoding.processBlock (package:pointycastle/asymmetric/oaep.dart:169:14)
#2      _processInBlocks (package:ee2e/main.dart:46:28)
#3      rsaDecrypt (package:ee2e/main.dart:105:10)
#4      main (package:ee2e/main.dart:135:18)
#5      _runMain.<anonymous closure> (dart:ui/hooks.dart:301:23)
#6      _delayEntrypointInvocation.<anonymous closure> (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:297:19)
#7      _RawReceivePort._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:184:12)

The first 2 debugPrint's are different because of the encryption method but the second array of bytes does match the one in the first example but this time it gives an error while decrypting.
FULL CODE:
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:math';
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:pointycastle/src/platform_check/platform_check.dart';
import "package:pointycastle/export.dart";
import 'package:basic_utils/basic_utils.dart';

AsymmetricKeyPair<RSAPublicKey, RSAPrivateKey> generateRSAkeyPair(
    SecureRandom secureRandom,
    {int bitLength = 2048}) {
  // Create an RSA key generator and initialize it

  // final keyGen = KeyGenerator('RSA'); // Get using registry
  final keyGen = RSAKeyGenerator();

  keyGen.init(ParametersWithRandom(
      RSAKeyGeneratorParameters(BigInt.parse('65537'), bitLength, 64),
      secureRandom));

  // Use the generator

  final pair = keyGen.generateKeyPair();

  // Cast the generated key pair into the RSA key types

  final myPublic = pair.publicKey as RSAPublicKey;
  final myPrivate = pair.privateKey as RSAPrivateKey;

  return AsymmetricKeyPair<RSAPublicKey, RSAPrivateKey>(myPublic, myPrivate);
}

Uint8List _processInBlocks(AsymmetricBlockCipher engine, Uint8List input) {
  final numBlocks = input.length ~/ engine.inputBlockSize +
      ((input.length % engine.inputBlockSize != 0) ? 1 : 0);

  final output = Uint8List(numBlocks * engine.outputBlockSize);

  var inputOffset = 0;
  var outputOffset = 0;
  while (inputOffset < input.length) {
    final chunkSize = (inputOffset + engine.inputBlockSize <= input.length)
        ? engine.inputBlockSize
        : input.length - inputOffset;

    outputOffset += engine.processBlock(
        input, inputOffset, chunkSize, output, outputOffset);

    inputOffset += chunkSize;
  }

  return (output.length == outputOffset)
      ? output
      : output.sublist(0, outputOffset);
}

SecureRandom exampleSecureRandom() {

  final secureRandom = SecureRandom('Fortuna')
    ..seed(KeyParameter(
        Platform.instance.platformEntropySource().getBytes(32)));
  return secureRandom;
}

Uint8List rsaSign(RSAPrivateKey privateKey, Uint8List dataToSign) {
  //final signer = Signer('SHA-256/RSA'); // Get using registry
  final signer = RSASigner(SHA256Digest(), '0609608648016503040201');

  // initialize with true, which means sign
  signer.init(true, PrivateKeyParameter<RSAPrivateKey>(privateKey));

  final sig = signer.generateSignature(dataToSign);

  return sig.bytes;
}

bool rsaVerify(
    RSAPublicKey publicKey, Uint8List signedData, Uint8List signature) {
  //final signer = Signer('SHA-256/RSA'); // Get using registry
  final sig = RSASignature(signature);

  final verifier = RSASigner(SHA256Digest(), '0609608648016503040201');

  // initialize with false, which means verify
  verifier.init(false, PublicKeyParameter<RSAPublicKey>(publicKey));

  try {
    return verifier.verifySignature(signedData, sig);
  } on ArgumentError {
    return false; // for Pointy Castle 1.0.2 when signature has been modified
  }
}

Uint8List rsaEncrypt(RSAPublicKey myPublic, Uint8List dataToEncrypt) {
  final encryptor = OAEPEncoding(RSAEngine())
    ..init(true, PublicKeyParameter<RSAPublicKey>(myPublic)); // true=encrypt

  return _processInBlocks(encryptor, dataToEncrypt);
}

Uint8List rsaDecrypt(RSAPrivateKey myPrivate, Uint8List cipherText) {
  final decryptor = OAEPEncoding(RSAEngine())
    ..init(false, PrivateKeyParameter<RSAPrivateKey>(myPrivate)); // false=decrypt

  return _processInBlocks(decryptor, cipherText);
}

 main(){
   final pair = generateRSAkeyPair(exampleSecureRandom());
   final public = pair.publicKey;
   final private = pair.privateKey;
   
   final privatePEM = CryptoUtils.encodeRSAPrivateKeyToPem(private);
   final publicPem = CryptoUtils.encodeRSAPublicKeyToPem(public);
   
   final privateRSA = CryptoUtils.rsaPrivateKeyFromPem(privatePEM);
   final publicRSA = CryptoUtils.rsaPublicKeyFromPem(publicPem);
  
   //THIS DOES WORK
   var normal_text = "hi";
   var bytes = utf8.encode(normal_text);
   var encoded = rsaEncrypt(publicRSA, bytes);
   var base64_encoded = base64Encode(encoded);
   debugPrint(base64_encoded); // used this in var base64
   var base64_decoded = base64Decode(base64_encoded);
   var decoded = rsaDecrypt(privateRSA, base64_decoded);


   //THIS DOES NOT WORK
   var base64 = "v7GAywDddNahHhS4sHqibbKiPOpyn7fHTSFJsHyGxkr5of931db/pL8kQK+35bJ4erEKTxoP1qA1OGM/i47j7Apc4l1gb79X3pwyeocIa1MW94QyJErtUvPMc3BL5whzan6gkExsJ6b1xPe3M4X7N+YoaoQNNTozcF8TT7hXBy/NTjKimruR3AZDXsAe7VvtO+suHMn40ot15WV+jgE9fwKM6pFkgYK5IK6XR0X9K+BKHCXk5tGBy70pqdrKQxeLRLs0AREH+UDHYzuwbwDBym7uVsXBFCLL3P7jf+D4UbQEeECHs27UVQODQ/7Et9YbI1BIM1UOPW2Mts0zltqPDQ==";
   var encrypted_base64 = base64Decode(base64);
   var decoded2 = rsaDecrypt(privateRSA, encrypted_base64);


}


The main() function generates a new key pair for each call. So if you generate a ciphertext in one call and try to decrypt it in another call, this will fail because the public key for encryption and the private key for decryption are not associated.

What you need to do is generate a key pair and persist the keys somewhere (e.g. as PEM keys) so that they can be imported if required. Then encrypt with the public key of this key pair and decrypt with the associated private key.

@Topaco your right that's a issue. although this should not happen in the original project and only in my example. I will look into this and update my question if there is another issue.
